# How to call real Java code from a CouchDB javascript View?

Tags: java, javascript, couchdb

I've been experimenting with CouchDB and my only complaint so far, which actually is sort of a show-stopper, is the awkward programming environment for Views. I would really prefer to have access to Java or any other language with access to a full IDE, JUnit, etc. Otherwise it's impossible to code any complex views.

Is there any way around this other than the Cloudant hosted solution? I really need my development environment to be fully contained within my laptop (so I can develop offline).

Comment: Views should execute really quickly ... they need to be as fast as possible since they are reading/writing for every document that is stored into CouchDB.

Comment: https://github.com/jimklo/Barista/wiki